# python: is there a frequency function?

Tags: python, excel, vba

in excel there is a frequency function:

> The Excel FREQUENCY function This
>   useful function can analyse a series
>   of values and summarise them into a
>   number of specified ranges. For
>   example the heights of some children
>   can be grouped in to four categories
>   of [Less than 150cm]; [151 - 160cm];
>   [161 - 170cm]; [More than 170cm].
>
> Would you like to learn more?
>
> Excel 2003 Formulas by John Walkenbach
>   (with CD)
>
> FREQUENCY() is an unusual array
>   function and it works differently to
>   most other normal functions. It can
>   not simply be typed into a cell or
>   even entered properly using the Excel
>   Function Wizard.
>
> Note that this function does not
>   analyse values into categories e.g.
>   household expenditure into groups such
>   as gas, electricity, water, rates etc.
>   To perform this kind of analysis an
>   Advanced Filter may be appropriate.
>
> The frequency function has two
>   arguments - the first is the range of
>   cells containing values to be
>   analysed; the second is the range of
>   cells containing the upper values of
>   each group banding. e.g.
>   =FREQUENCY(A3:A120, B6:B10)
>
> The second argument (the group upper
>   limits) will exclude any values which
>   exceed the highest category or
>   banding. The function allows you to
>   take account of this and extend the
>   range of analysis to an additional
>   category which contains all values
>   that exceed the specified upper limit.

http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xlfreq.htm

is there such a thing in python?

Comment: (I don't have Excel atm.) Does `FREQUENCY` merely count the number of data points in each bucket, or does it bucket the data points themselves? That is, is `FREQUENCY( [ 145, 155 ] )` meant to give `{ 'Less than 150cm': 1, ... }` or `{ 'Less than 150cm': 145, ...`?

Comment: If the latter, `numpy.histogram` is your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy
numpy.histogram( [ <data> ], [ <bins> ] )
```

[Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram):

> ```
> numpy.histogram(a, bins=10, range=None, normed=False, weights=None)
> ```
>
> Compute the histogram of a set of data.
>   Parameters:
>
> `a` : array_like
>   Input data. The histogram is computed over the flattened array.
>
> `bins` : int or sequence of scalars, optional
>   If bins is an int, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the
>   given range (10, by default). If bins
>   is a sequence, it defines the bin
>   edges, including the rightmost edge,
>   allowing for non-uniform bin widths.
>
> `range` : (float, float), optional 
>   The lower and upper range of the bins. If not provided, range is
>   simply (a.min(), a.max()). Values
>   outside the range are ignored.
>
> `normed` : bool, optional
>   If False, the result will contain the number of samples in each
>   bin. If True, the result is the value
>   of the probability density function at
>   the bin, normalized such that the
>   integral over the range is 1. Note
>   that the sum of the histogram values
>   will not be equal to 1 unless bins of
>   unity width are chosen; it is not a
>   probability mass function.
>
> `weights` : array_like, optional
>   An array of weights, of the same shape as a. Each value in a only
>   contributes its associated weight
>   towards the bin count (instead of 1).
>   If normed is True, the weights are
>   normalized, so that the integral of
>   the density over the range remains 1
>
> Returns:
>
> `hist` : array
>   The values of the histogram. See normed and weights for a
>   description of the possible semantics.
>
> `bin_edges` : array of dtype float
>   Return the bin edges (length(hist)+1).

You may have to [install numpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/) first.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to use `numpy.histogram`, but if you don't want to install numpy, here is one that works just like Excel:

```
def frequency(data, bins):
    # work with local sorted copy of bins for performance
    bins = bins[:]
    bins.sort()
    freqs = [0] * (len(bins)+1)
    for item in data:
        for i, bin_val in enumerate(bins):
            if item <= bin_val:
                freqs[i] += 1
                break
        else:
            freqs[len(bins)] += 1
    return freqs
```

Here's the example in Excel's help translated to python:

```
>>> data = [79, 85, 78, 85, 50, 81, 95, 88, 97]
... bins = [70, 79, 89]
... print frequency(data, bins)
[1, 2, 4, 2]
```

There is one minor difference.  In Excel, if `bins` is empty, the length of data is returned as an integer.  This python version returns that integer in a list.  The reason for this is that the Python version will return a consistent data type (and still give the correct answer).

Answer (score 1):

based on what the referenced page http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xlfreq.htm states i wrote a function i'm sure that there are faster ways to do it but i'm sure this one is correct

```
def FREQUENCY(values, bands, max=None):
   counts = [0]*(len(bands)+1)
   for v in values:
       for i,b in enumerate(bands):
           if v <= b:
               counts[i] += 1
               break
           else if v > max:
               counts[-1] += 1
               break
   return counts
```

Comment: Excel's FREQUENCY returns an array that is one element longer than bands.  This version does not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there is such function in Python, but obviously you can write it:

```
def frequency(values, groups):
    # Build the solution
    toret = dict()
    toret[ None ] = list()

    # Sort them
    values.sort()
    groups.sort()

    # Run over groups
    i = 0
    for maxValue in groups:
        while ( ( values[ i ] < maxValue ) and ( i < len( values ) ) ):
            if ( toret.get( maxValue ) == None ):
                toret[ maxValue ] = list()
            toret[ maxValue ].append( values[ i ] )
            i += 1

        if ( i >= len( values ) ):
            break

    if ( i < len( values ) ):
        while( i < len( values ) ):
            toret[ None ].append( values[ i ] )
            i += 1

    return toret


l=[ 15,9,3,5,6,4,8,2,1,7,11,12 ]
g=[ 3,6,9 ]
print( frequency( l, g ) )
```

The result here is a dictionary, in which each element is one of the max values in the groups list. You can find the frequency by computing the length of each list.

The result is:

```
{None: [9, 11, 12, 15], 9: [6, 7, 8], 3: [1, 2], 6: [3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: If you refer to the parenthesis in sentences such as: "print( frequency( l, g ) )", then they are due to the use of Python 3. IF you refer to them in "if ( i < len( values ) ):", then it is personal use.